# Xcode CI bot errors during unit testing (Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish)

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, continuous-integration, sentestingkit

We recently set up some [Xcode bots](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html) with an iOS app to automatically build and test an app I'm working on. If I do just build and analyze, the build process works fine. If I set it to run tests, it ends up with a variable amount of errors that end with `Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish`. For example, the most recent run showed:

> Run test suite TimeClockTestCase encountered an error (Unexpected
>   TestCaseDidFinish) testParseResponseString encountered an error
>   (Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish) testGetIntegrationID encountered an
>   error (Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish)

And the one before that had just one error:

> testAddChildObjectTypeTimeClockEvent encountered an error (Unexpected
>   TestSuiteWillFinish)

The integration results show all tests as passed, no matter what errors are displayed. If I run the tests directly via Xcode (instead of running the bot on the server), there are no errors and the same number of tests are passed.

What causes these errors and how can I eliminate them?

---

These are the logs from the TimeClockTestCase:

```
Test Suite 'TimeClockTestCase' started at 2014-02-23 23:11:09 +0000
2014-02-23 18:11:09.653 -0500 [TimeClockResponseCommand parseResponseString] [Line 74] W: Unsupported action number "3" in TIMECLOCK response command

Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testAddChildObjectTypeTimeClockEvent]' started.
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testAddChildObjectTypeTimeClockEvent]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testAddChildObjectTypeTimeClockMode]' started.
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testAddChildObjectTypeTimeClockMode]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testTimeclockEventColl]' started.
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testTimeclockEventColl]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testTimeclockModeColl]' started.
Test Case '-[TimeClockTestCase testTimeclockModeColl]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Suite 'TimeClockTestCase' finished at 2014-02-23 23:11:09 +0000.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same random behavior. I was able to identify that I was making an **Asynchronous** call, and testing it, was what caused this random `Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish`.

As I'm using `Kiwi`, what I did is to wait a little bit the end of the asynchronous call like indicated here (https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Asynchronous-Testing) for those specicfic asynchronous calls.

Hope this help!

Comment: This turns out to have been the case, although the fix was slightly different because we use CocoaLumberjack instead of Kiwi. For reference, I changed `#define LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED YES` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue of `Unexpected TestSuiteWillFinish` calls causing tests to abort. In our case, it was due to excessive debug logging. Disabling our logging caused tests to pass reliably again.

That wouldn't seem to be the cause of your issue, but maybe it's a hint?

My offhand guess is that the XCTest runner has some kind of timeout. So check that your test executes in a timely manner?